# Hibernation not working and excessive battery drain on suspend on Ubuntu 22.04 with DELL XPS 15

Tags: suspend, dell, battery, hibernate

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my DELL XPS 15, and I'm facing two related issues: hibernation doesn't work, and the suspend feature drains a significant amount of battery power. I would appreciate any help or suggestions to troubleshoot and resolve these problems.

Specifically, here are the details of the issues I'm encountering:

Hibernation not working: When I try to hibernate my system, nothing happens

Excessive battery drain on suspend: When I choose the suspend option to save power, I notice that the battery drains more quickly than it should. I've made sure that no resource-intensive applications are running in the background, but the drain is still noticeable. This is a concern as it affects the overall battery life and mobility of my laptop.

Here are some additional details that may be helpful:

Laptop model: DELL XPS 15
Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

I've searched online for solutions, but I haven't found any specific answers that address these problems for Ubuntu 22.04. I'm hoping that someone with knowledge and experience in Ubuntu and DELL XPS laptops can provide guidance on how to diagnose and fix these issues.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!